# Does hypothesis testing require each variant has a distribution with a fixed mean?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

Attached is the graph of daily conversion rates from an actual online experimentation(A/B testing). Obviously we can see the conversion rates of both control and test variants are **trending down**. Can we still apply hypothesis testing(either Classic or Bayesian) on such case? Does hypothesis testing require each variant has a distribution with a **fixed** mean?

[image]

Comment: Exactly what hypothesis or hypotheses do you wish to test?

Comment: Null hypothesis: both conversion rates of control and test variants are equal, Alternative hypothesis: they are different.

Comment: The non-parametric eyeball test says: "Not significant", no matter the assumptions. But actually, the setting is very interesting: You have paired data, a bounded response close to 0 plus a relevant confounding factor (time), resp. a time series aspect.

Comment: @Michael How can you conduct a test with so little information about the sample sizes?

Comment: @whuber: A very good question.

Comment: My key question is stated in the subject. In other words, can hypothesis testing be applied to moving conversion rates/means? It seems all test statistics assume fixed means, for example, t-test.